# How to handle android screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout

I am just getting into Android development and have a couple of questions about layouts.

I have a RelativeLayout as my root element and inside that I have the following items in the order:

TextView, TextView, Button, Button, Button, TextView

When I view the layout/activity in portrait orientation everything is fine. However when I switch my phone to landscape orientation the design "bunches up" and the first Button overlaps the second TextView and I can only partially see the last Button's background color and the last TextView text lands over that Button.

There is no scrollbar or means to view the whole display. Is there a way I can keep my layout the same when the screen rotates? I know I will not fit those 6 elements in a landscape orientation but I thought the layout would simply be scrollable to view the rest?

Comment: You can create layout for landscape in layout-land folder. You have set the same name as portial layout for example for layout/main.xml will be layout-land/main.xml

Comment: You want to keep your screen on portrait mode?

Comment: You can put your items inside a ScrollView, otherwise you can create another xml file in *layout-land* (with the same name) to represent your view on landscape mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple trick is to just wrap your whole RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Keep in mind that the Scrollview can only contain, one layout element, in thisi case since you already have a root relativelayout that's just fine!

When the screen contains content I usually pu the entire layout or a big part of it inside a ScrollView, not only it will help users to see content when they switch their devices to portrait mode, but  will also help user with devices with smaller screens see all your content

You can easily check how things will look using the layout editor on Eclipse or Android Studio.

On Android Studio, just open your layout file and switch to the design tab, then on the upper side there is an icon to change orientation.

Answer (score 0):

1. A `LinearLayout` will guarantee that the views are placed below each other, not overlapping. A `RelativeLayout` does not do that if you don't specify each Views position in Relation to each other.
2. Android does not make your Layout scrollable by default if they don't fit on the screen. You have to wrap your Layout in a `ScrollView`.
3. As was pointed out, you can create different layouts for different screen sizes. You can also just create one with a `ScrollView`, it will make no difference when everything fits on the screen anyways (portrait mode. )